# OSS LWC app on Heroku Css Fails to load

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, heroku, lwc-oss

I am trying to run an OSS LWC app on heroku using SLDS via synthetic shadow dom.
When I run it locally using `heroku local web` everything looks great.

[image: beautiful]

When it makes all the way to my Heroku site, I see unstyled garbage with an error message on the chrome console saying "Refused to apply style from 'https://some-app.herokuapp.com/SLDS/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

[image]

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Here is my index html and js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>my app</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/SLDS/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css" />
        <base href="/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-app></my-app>
    </body>
</html>

import '@lwc/synthetic-shadow';
import { buildCustomElementConstructor } from 'lwc';
import MyApp from 'my/app';

customElements.define('my-app', buildCustomElementConstructor(MyApp));
```

Comment: Is there a CSS file available at that URI?

Comment: Yes, the CSS file is present at the specified location

Comment: Hi there, I just had the same issue and it seems like the css files are just not watched when running `npm run watch` or something other here fails. For me restarting it, did the trick

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue on a web app on Nodejs. Any pointers on that?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue.

Try adding the assets folder that contains the styling in your public folder. This worked for me and I can now use SLDS in my app.